# Cannot import wsdl:portType in VS 2010 - not common answer

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I'm Getting this like others have, however following the advice to uncheck reuse didn't help me.  I have a Windows 7 OS with IIS 7.5.  Any ideas?

```
Warning 1   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension:     System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Schema with target namespace 'http://mybpservice/2012-03' could not be found.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://mybpservice/2012-03']/wsdl:portType[@name='IBPService']
```

Add Service Reference in VS 2010 "sees the service and operations" but doesn't generate any code.

Comment: please publish the wsdl, including any referenced schema. you can also mail me if it is confidential

Comment: I can but just to let you know, if I create the out of the box WCF app that you get with "Hello world" that gives me the same thing (without changing a thing) ... seems like my ServiceRegModel is hosed or something.

Comment: try to use svcutil.exe directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is resolved....

I had to add WCF 3.5 in under control panel, then remove it again. That seemed to resolve my issue. I was then getting my references added on both services I mentioned.
Then hadd issues with SQL logins, had to add in the Users into my sql db for the apppools .
So it was something to do with ServiceModelReg.exe (3.0 vs 4.0) on the same WIndows 7 machine with IIS 7.5

Now I'm good to go.